# TFS Get Latest without readonly flags

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Is there any way to configure TFS to not mark all files as read only when the 'Get Latest' command is executed?  Maybe there is a special plugin or something that can do this?  It is monumentally annoying to have to clear these flags manually when the need arises.

Comment: Don't know of any way to make tf get do what you want unfortunately. But kind of curious as to why you would want this?

Comment: a classic example would be moles assemblies.  You have to check them in for other developers to build the associated project, but they won't build if they are read only.

Comment: Also, all of the files are already in source control, and TFS does have the ability to detect conflicts, so why bother locking everything up?

Comment: @A.R. - In the most recent version of Moles, the DLLs aren't checked in anymore.  A solution to your problem could be an upgrade to a later version of Moles.

Comment: @NickNieslanik - Maybe so, but that is just one of many cases that I can think of.  I can't just upgrade all of my problems away.

Comment: @A.R. - Fair enough, just trying to help man. But to be honest I think that if you are altering files and not checking them in or if you have a ton of checked-in items that change all of the time due to build processes or some other bit of automation and you aren't checked THAT in, then your problem isn't the read-only attribute, it's your process.

Comment: @NickNieslanik - It doesn't happen very often, (quite rare in fact) but it still happens.  There are also many other developers on a growing team that have to deal with this stuff too.  And just to clarify, it is TFS that is actually changing the files (by erroneously marking them readonly)  In doing so it is introducing a time sink into the process, so I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: @A.R. I still don't understand why you assert that TFS is 'erroneously' marking the files read-only.  What's 'erroneous' about it?  TFS marks version-controlled files read-only when they aren't checked out.  Is that erroneous?

Comment: @NickNieslankik - Yes it is.  TFS is making an assumption about a property of a file (readonly) that is useful outside of the context of a source control system.

Comment: The reason they do this is to help avoid the situation where people make changes to files outside of VS, and don't realize that TFS will never pick up those changes because you never checked-out the file.  The read-only flag is meant to make sure you do a check-out before modifying a file.

Comment: @Dylan - I understand the theory of it, but it is still a double-dip at the end of the day.  Let's say that I have a number of files that I want to keep marked as readonly, but are in TFS.  Since everything gets blanketed as readonly, now I have no way of communicating my original intent, and even worse, other users are under the impressions that they can "checkout" the item and edit as they please.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by communicate your intent?  If your intent is to edit the files, and you don't want anybody else editing at the same time you would check-out from TFS with an exclusive lock, and this would turn read-only off and communicate your intent to other team members.

Comment: @A.R. - I agree with Dylan.  I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @NickNieslanik  Disagreeing is OK with me, I'm not trying to pick a fight or anything.  But for the record, TFS is the only source control system I have used that does this kind of stuff (out of three).  I mean, would you expect it to change other properties of the file system without your permission?  Names, times, archive flags, etc?

Comment: @Dylan - The intent would be that the file is readonly and should stay that way.  Exclusive locks are the domain of source control, and readonly flags (and other attributes) are the domain of a file system.

Comment: @A.R. No I wouldn't expect it to change the File Name, but other file properties would be fine with me if they stated in the Doc that it was expected and I could plan for it.  My only point was that your claim that it's erroneous isn't accurate.  They clearly state that they do it and it's done for purpose so it's not erroneous, you just don't like it and it interferes with your process.  I've used Source Control systems that both use and ignore the read-only flag and I'm fine with either way as long as it's well documented and known to team members.

Comment: @NickNieslanik - A well documented error is still an error.

Comment: @A.R. - You crack me up. It's just different.  Different does not = wrong.

Comment: note: in TFS 2012 this is done via Local Workspaces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19861052/76859

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, there is no way to configure TFS to not mark all files as read only during a *Get Latest Version* action.

As you willl probably know, it is possible to do this as a second separate step in a TFS Build template by customization or using the **tf edit** command from the command line.

A good post on the internal workings of the TFS Get command is available at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243654/TFS-Get-Latest-VS-Get-Specific-Version. The same post also gives suggestions to write a tool yourself that is able to use the TFS API. Of course you can do whatever you want in that case.

Comment: Another option is to attrib the tree and then run tfpt online before checking in.  For the next version, we are changing TFS to use read-write files rather than readonly.  You can read more at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx.